# How to assign a specific dollar amount to a name in excel? Capital One = to $50.00 Dollars

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to assign a dollar amount to names in excel. For example I want "Chase Credit Card" to equal $40.00,   I want "Capital One" to equal $50.00,   "Discovery Credit" = $25.00,  "Lights" = $500.00 and so on...   Is there a way to assign a $dollar.value to a "name" in excel?

Comment: Can you post your attempts at doing this? What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Comment: What exactly are the names?  Are they cell values?  Variables in VBA?  Can you give us a clear example of how you are using these names?  At first thought a simple 2 column list and using VLOOKUP comes to mind.

Comment: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: if amounts assigned are always the same, then build a lookup table and then use a lookup formula.

Answer (score 0):

Excel allows one to assign range names to a single cell or a collection of cells, either contiguous or non-contiguous. The website [HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/242652/how-to-assign-a-name-to-a-range-of-cells-in-excel/) provides the information necessary to create these names.

One selects a cell or range, and under the Formula tab, selects Define Name. Enter the name desired within the constraints (no spaces, special characters, etc.) and press enter.

That name can then be used in formula, i.e., =lights * 1.06 would provide a 6 percent increase in the value in the cell created with that name.